# Selectors in Swift 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, selector, swift4

I was wondering if there is a more 'swift 4' way of creating a selector and calling a function? I am wanting to have the click of the Status Bar Button to call a simple print command from a function, but is this outdated or is there a more efficient 'swift' way of doing this?

```
button.action = #selector(myFunction)

@objc func myFunction (sender: NSStatusBarButton) {
    print("Hi")
}
```

Comment: That's the price of the Objective-C target/action legacy API.

Comment: What you have is exactly the way to do it. Cocoa Touch apps still use an Objective-C runtime, and that’s what selectors interface with.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there's any good way to avoid using the target/action pattern **under the hood**, but you can definitely try to hide it.

Personally I use ReactiveSwift for all callbacks so I never have to use this awkward objc syntax. Another way to do it would be to hide this inside an extension. For instance, you can try something like:

```
extension UIButton {

    private struct AssociatedKeys {
        static var TouchUpClosure = "touchUpClosure"
    }

    internal var onTouchUpInside: ((UIButton) -> ())? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.TouchUpClosure) as? (UIButton) -> ()            
        }

        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(
                self,
                &AssociatedKeys.TouchUpClosure,
                newValue as? (UIButton) -> (), objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC
            )
            button.action = #selector(executeTouchUpInside:)
        }
    }

    @objc func executeTouchUpInside(sender: UIButton) {
        self.touchUpInside(sender)
    }
}
```

Which allows you to use a "more swift" syntax (no `@objc` or `#selector`):

```
button.onTouchUpInside = { _ in print("Hi") }
```

---

Disclaimer - I haven't checked if this exact code compiles, this post is more about sharing an idea.

Comment: You would also need to set the button's target to `self` in order for the local action to be called.

Comment: Also avoid confusing using `UIButton` (`UIControl`) `addTarget` with the question's `NSStatusBarButton` (`NSControl`) separate `action` and `target` properties.